# seaborn - how to add mean bar to barplot grouped with hue

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, seaborn

I've got code as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import seaborn as sns

data=[np.random.randint(2018,2020,size=(30)),      
      np.random.randint(1,13,size=(30)),
      np.random.randint(1,101,size=(30)),
      np.random.randint(1,101,size=(30))]

cols=['year','month','val','val1']

data=pd.DataFrame(data).T

data.columns=cols

data1=[np.random.randint(1,13,size=(30)),
      np.random.randint(1,101,size=(30)),
      np.random.randint(1,101,size=(30))]

cols1=['month','val','val1']

data1=pd.DataFrame(data1).T

data1.columns=cols1


sns.barplot(data=data,x='month',y='val',hue='year',ci=False)

sns.barplot(data=data,x='month',y='val',estimator=np.mean,ci=False)
```

to produce barplots
and in fact I get two bar plots

[image]

and the second with mean for each month

[image]

but I would like to have one plot with three columns for each month including mean bar. Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas' plot function:

```
(data.pivot_table(index='month',columns='year',
                  values='val', margins=True, 
                  margins_name='Mean')
     .drop('Mean')
     .plot.bar()
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: One question how margins attribute works? It gave mean without function declaring. Does it give mean always? There is only brief description in pandas documantation.

Comment: The margin function is defined by `aggfunc`, which is `'mean'` by default.